# How to format my Mac and install Snow Leopard from scratch?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, formatting

I want to wipe my current Leopard installation and install Snow Leopard on my mac. What is the correct way to achieve this?

It seems like I would need to boot into some disk utility in order to format it, but I'm not quite sure how to do that.

### Solution

- Insert the Snow Leopard DVD.
- Restart your computer.
- While your computer is restarting, hold down the alt/option key. It will then ask you which drive you want to boot from. Select your DVD drive.
- From there you can select Disk Utlity from the Utilities menu and format the drive, or choose the "erase and install" option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boot from the Mac OS X Snow Leopard Install DVD, and from the "Utilities" menu, choose "Disk utility". From there you can reformat your hard disk. After doing so, quit Disk Utility and you can perform a clean install.

**EDIT**: Apparently there is also an "Erase and Install" option. (I haven't used this before myself). [See more details here](http://www.tuaw.com/2007/10/26/leopard-how-to-clean-install/).

Here's an [official apple support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1545) about all the installation options available.

It occurred to me after posting this that, while your question clearly states you want to format your disk, I wanted to mention that **this will erase all data on your disk, including applications and your data**. So *make a backup first*. Alternatively, you could just perform an "Archive and Install" which will give you a clean OS, but leave your data and applications in tact.

Comment: I didn't know how to boot from the DVD. For all who are wondering, hold down the alt/option key while booting and it will ask you which drive you want to boot from.

Comment: @misbehavens: Sorry, I should have mentioned that :-) You can also choose a disk to start up from via the "Startup Disk" preference pane in System Preferences.